# CFCOMPILE - Precompiling ColdFusion pages & Sourceless distribution

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I see that pre-compiling pages to java classes will increase performance, while using the -deploy command will encode the pages to java bytecode, thus hiding the source code.

Questions:

Can both of the above be done? Pre-compiling the application, then encoding them?

Is updating sourceless pages & cfc's as simple as encoding the newly updated files locally, then overwrite the older ones on the server?

Thank you for your contributions.

Answer (score 3):

It's worth noting that byte code won't 'secure' your code if someone gets onto your server. There is nothing to stop someone from decompiling your code using tools like [this](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/).

There is offical Adobe info [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Admin/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbf364104-7fd0.html) on sourceless distribution but I haven't tried it. Remember, the compile hit if only on the first request (provided you have your CF admin setting correct) so the boost isn't for every request.

I'd also prefer to 'secure' my source code in other ways, i.e. making sure the server is secure.

Comment: Thank you for your input. Would just like to get it straight. According to http://coldfused.blogspot.com/2008/01/encrypted-cfml-templates.html Talking about cfcompile & decompiling, I quote "Though there are many Java decompilers available which can convert the class file to approximate java source file, it will be a huge huge task to write a decompiler which can generate cfm code for class file". Is this correct?

Comment: That's a fair enough statement - you'd need a de-interpret from Java -> CF. I'm not sure if anyone has written one of those! Be aware though that it's just not a guarantee, someone might do it in future - as the poster says it's not the same as encryption. One thought is that with the increase in SaaS (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_as_a_service) apps, more and more services are being provided over the Internet rather than customers having to install the software. There are of course cases where SaaS will not be possible nor desirable.